# Twin axis chart without frames

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would try to plot a chart with twin axes and without the frame, but if I use the frameon=False function I got still the chart with the frame. What could be the problem? If I make a single chart with a single ax then it works. My code:

```
fig  = plt.subplots(1, figsize =(17,21))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 10), (0, 0), rowspan= 2,colspan=4,frameon=False)
ax1_tw = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(data[['SPX500']],  linewidth=1.5, linestyle=('-'))
ax1_tw.plot(data[['VIX_Close']] ,'k',  linewidth=1.5, linestyle=('-'))
ax1_tw.plot(data[['VIX_Close_avg']] ,'orange',  linewidth=1.5, linestyle=(':'))
ax1.set(title='SP500')
ax1.set(xlabel='Date')
ax1.set(ylabel='SP500')
ax1_tw.set(ylabel='VIX')
ax1_tw.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
ax1.legend(('SP500',),loc=2, frameon=False)
ax1_tw.legend(('VIX',),loc=1, frameon=False)
ax1_tw.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.show()
```

andthe result is:[image]

Comment: Has the below answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a misunderstanding here I guess. The problem is that `frameon=False` does not apply to the axes frames but the frame of the legend box. Below is an example to explain it.

**Figure with `frameon=True`**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(1, 30)

ax.plot(x, x**2, '-g', label='$x^2$')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, 1/x, '-r', label='$1/x$')

ax.legend(('$x^2$',), loc='best', fontsize=16)
ax2.legend(('$1/x$',), loc='best', fontsize=16)
```

[image]

**Figure with `frameon=False`**

```
ax.legend(('$x^2$',), loc='best', frameon=False, fontsize=16)
ax2.legend(('$1/x$',), loc='best', frameon=False, fontsize=16)
```

[image]

**What you need** instead is to turn off the axes using (you can turn on the legend frame if you want)

```
ax.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
```

[image]